# Azure Rest API Read VM Peformance Metrics

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine

I am trying the read the performance metrics of vms in the azure cloud using the rest api. As per the this link ( azure documentation ) http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/documentation/articles/cloud-services-how-to-monitor/#accessverbose

but when i try to fetch the tables that are available for a particular from a storage account i am not getting empty table list.

Please correct me what the ways we can capture vm performance metrics using the rest api to integrate with 3rd party system management providers.